# Wordpress: Multiple blogs on different domains hosted by one host

Tags: dns, wordpress

My goal is to run multiple Wordpress "blog" sites with one admin login/interface.

I'm currently hosted through GoDaddy and I have installed Wordpress in example1.com/wordpress

I want to have example1.com and example2.com direct to the same wordpress installation but different settings and different content.  Has anyone attempted this?  How would I set this up?

I've read the [docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) on how to Create A Network but ran into confusion when I read *"You cannot create a network in the following cases: "WordPress address (URL)" is different from "Site address (URL)". "*

Does that mean what I'm trying to do is not possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You cannot create a network in the following cases: "WordPress address (URL)" is different from "Site address (URL)".

means you cannot have example1.com/wordpress and have it act like example1.com.

If you want the subsites (which in your case will be example1.com/wordpress/site2/ and example1.com/wordpress/site3/ ) to act like example2.com and example3.com, then you need to set up the network and install the Domain Mapping plugin.

- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/
- http://gmichaelguy.com/blog/2010/11/28/my-wordpress-3-0-multi-site-domain-mapping-with-godaddy/